# How to load custom query data in select box in symfony 2

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1

I have a table as below:

```
items
-id (pk) AI
-user_id (fk) references users
-title
-description
```

I have a form page which requires authenticated users. I want to fill the select box with items that belongs to the user (like select * from items where user_id=loggedinUserId)

I looked at the documentation and I found this:

```
 $builder->add('items', 'entity', array(
    'class' => 'AcmeHelloBundle:Items',
    'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
       return $er->createQueryBuilder('i')
        ->orderBy('i.title', 'ASC');
    },
));
```

My question is how can I pass the authenticated user id to this query in symfony 2.1 forms ?

Comment: you can access the user from the app with `$this->('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();` or from a .twig file with `{{ app.user }}`

Comment: i want to load the items into the select box which belongs to the user who has been logged in. I dont want to load all the items and then check whether they belong to that user or not in the view. i have many items entity and that would be waste of resource

Comment: first, are you using doctrine? Second have you defined your relation in your database entity? If you do you can access them directly with the user object with like a `$user->getItems()`. Else, just do a where( $user->getId())` (or something like that) from the user object that you've retrieved in the ways I've defined before. There is supposed to be a "where" function in the query builder

Comment: yes I am using doctrine, all relations have been defined in doctrine entities. I have been successful in loading the items entity in the select box with custom query_builder. Problem is that how can i pass the logged_in user id to the query_builder and how to call

Comment: You should be able to load the items of the user with simply `$user->getItems()` with doctrine. Else just pass the id with the where function of the query builder. Get the user id from the security context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You have two possibilities:**

- inject the parameters via the constructor (**Constructor Injection**)
- inject the parameters via the options of the form

This [awesome thread](http://sf.khepin.com/2012/10/user-dependent-forms-in-symfony2/) show you an interesting way of doing it (from [@khepin](http://sf.khepin.com/about/)). However, as suggested by @Bernhard (see first comment), there is a simpler way in that case.

---

**METHOD 1- Constructor Injection : If you can't bother creating a suscriber etc... you can directly inject the security context into your form constructor :**

*ItemType:*

```
namespace Acme\HelloBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContextInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

classItemType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $class;

    /**
     * @var UserInterface
     */
    private $user;

    /**
     * @param string $class
     */
    public function __construct($class, SecurityContextInterface $securityContext)
    {
        $this->class = $class;
        $this->user = $securityContext->getRequest->getUser();
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {

                $username = $this->user->getUsername();    

                $builder->add('items', 'entity', array(
                    'class' => $this->class,
                    'multiple' => true,
                    'expanded' => true,
                    'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) use ($username) {
                        $query = $er->createQueryBuilder('i')
                            ->select(array('i'))
                            ->leftJoin('i.users', 'u')
                            ->andWhere('u.username = :username')
                            ->setParameter('username', $usename)
                            ->orderBy('i.title', 'ASC');

                        return $query;

                    },
                )
            ));

    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => $this->class,
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'acme_hello_item';
    }
}
```

*Declare it as a service:*

```
<parameters>
    <parameter key="acme_hello.item.class">Acme\HelloBundle\Entity\Item</parameter>
</parameters>

<services>
    <service id="merk_notification.filter.form.type" class="Acme\HelloBundle\Form\Type\ItemType">
        <tag name="form.type" alias="acme_hello_item" />

        <argument>%acme_hello.item.class%</argument>
        <argument type="service" id="security.context" />
    </service>
</services>
```

To build your form, you can now do :

```
    $formBuilder = $this->container->get('form.factory');
    $form = $formBuilder->createNamed('acme_hello_item', 'acme_hello_item');
```

Answer (score 3):

The solution offered by @Patt seems to be ideal but in my case, this form is used only once or in only one page. so i preferred to do as follow:

```
class ItemType extends AbstractType {

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
       $user=$options['user'];
       $builder->add('itemOffered', 'entity', array(
                'class' => 'TestBundle:Items',
                'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) use ($user) {
                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('i')
                              ->where('i.user =:user')
                              ->setParameter('user', $user);
                }
            ));
    }
}
```

In controller:

```
$form = $this->createForm(new ItemType(), new Item(),array('user' => $this->getUser()));
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this with just the Entity, if you have already got the data from within the controller with a ->findBy() for example